# Не создается и не записывается файл Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Столкнулся с проблемой, что функция не записывает и не сохраняет файл

Имеется такая функция:

```
def f_save_word_to_file(word):
    if word not in [ x.strip() for x in open(os.path.expanduser (save_word_to_file_fname)).readlines() ]:
        print(word, file = open(os.path.expanduser (save_word_to_file_fname), 'a'))
```

переменная:

```
save_word_to_file_fname = '~/saved_words'
```

По клику левой кнопки мышки должно смотреть есть ли такое слово и если нет, сохранять выбранное слово в данный файл
Библиотека os.path подключена,

```
import os, subprocess, sys
```

Другая функция на правой кнопке мыши работает без проблем (пробовал менять местами функции на ЛКМ и ПКМ, не помогло)
Также в этом скрипте имеются функции которые создают и записывают файл без проблем, кусок функции к примеру:

```
if save_translations:
        print('\n\n'.join(e[0] + '\n' + e[1] for e in pairs), file=open('urls/' + url.replace('/',"-"), 'a'))
        print('\n'+'=====/////-----'+'\n', file=open('urls/' + url.replace('/',"-"), 'a'))
        print(word_descr, file=open('urls/' + url.replace('/',"-"), 'a'))
```

Пробовал также сменить директорию, создавал файл вручную (посмотреть будет ли записываться), давал права 777 на папку, ничего не помогло, подскажите в чем проблема?

Comment: Что значит «не записывает»? Ошибку в консоли пишет или просто ничего не делает? У меня записывает, кстати.

Comment: просто ничего не делает, незнаю как посмотреть в консоли, это два скрипта на питоне и один на Lua для mvp player,если какая-то ошибка, скрипт просто не работотал бы вцелом

Comment: При нажатии кнопки в tkinter возникающая ошибка обычно просто игнорируется. Я не знаю, что как вы там запускаете, но вам нужно как-то запустить скрипт в консоли и почитать там ошибки. Впрочем, в любом случае у меня всё отлично пишется. Может, у вас файл `~/saved_words` вообще не существует?

Comment: ну, он действительно не существует, но я думал параметр "а" должен создавать файл если его не существует, но я пробывал создавать файл вручную и давать права 777, не помогло

Comment: Так ещё до параметра `a` вы же сперва читаете файл, там где readlines. Естественно, несуществующий файл не прочитается. А если и с созданным файлом не работает, то ищите консоль и читайте ошибку

Comment: не совсем понял как запустить отдельно скрипт в консоле и проверить, так как скрипт считывает только субтитры в плеере(в полноэкранном режиме) и не реагирует на другие слова вне плеера, а сам плеер изначально запускает Lua скрипт, который запускает python скрипт

Comment: Но вся эта дребедень тоже запускается где-то кем-то, например вами? Вот и запустите в консоли, не обязательно отдельно :) Если, конечно, вы где-то по пути stderr не отключили

Comment: Запустил я этот скрипт в eric IDE, только одна ошибка в конце файла, не связанная с данной функцией,  как я писал выше, устанавливал другую функцию под эту кнопку, кнопка и функция работают, вот вывод с консоли IDE: Python 3.6.4+ (default, Feb 12 2018, 08:25:03) [GCC 7.3.0] on debian, Standard >>> [py part] Starting interSubs ... Exception "unhandled IndexError" list index out of range File: /home/camel/.config/mpv/scripts/interSubs.py, Line: 1057

Comment: Попробуйте поменять `~ /filename` на `/home/user/filename` (с вашим именем пользователя, разумеется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так работает, всем спасибо

```
def f_save_word_to_file(word):
    if ( os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname)) and word not in [ x.strip() for x in open(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname)).readlines() ] ) or not os.path.isfile(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname)):
        print(word, file = open(os.path.expanduser(save_word_to_file_fname), 'a'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы записать слово в небольшой файл, если оно ещё не записано:

```
from contextlib import suppress
from pathlib import Path

def append_unless_present(word, path=Path('~/saved_words').expanduser()):
    with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
        if word in path.read_text().split():
            return  # already present

    with path.open('a') as file: # append
        print(word, file=file)
```

Если родительская директория не существует, то она автоматически не создаётся, чтобы неявно случайно по ошибке целую структуру директорий не создать.

Проверка на уникальность не эффективна для больших файлов и может сломаться, если пытаться вызвать эту функцию из нескольких потоков, процессов одновременно. Если необходимо, для увеличения скорости и чтобы добавить некоторую поддержку одновременного доступа, можно использовать встроенную базу данных SQLite:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect('words.sqlite')
db.execute('create table if not exists words(word text primary key) without rowid')
with db:
    db.execute('insert or ignore into words values(?)', (word,))
```

Для гарантированного параллельного доступа лучше внешнюю базу данных использовать такую как PostgreSQL.